# Delete pop up cookie of mailchimp form

Tags: javascript, html, popup, mailchimp

im using a sign up form of mailchimp, its a pop up but it have a cookie to dont show it again even if the user reloads the page.

this is the script:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"></script><script type="text/javascript">require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) { L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us15.list-manage.com","uuid":"3dd49f3f5fd6be7bc1be03226","lid":"049a3764fd"}) })</script>`

But i want allways display, is there a form to do this?

Answer (score 0):

the idea is to set their cookie as expired to have to possibility to display it next time.

Please check this page :
https://gist.github.com/scottmagdalein/259d878ad46ed6f2cdce